# Instantiate creates a clone in wrong position

Tags: unity

I have this prefab with this transform:

[image]

And then using this code to create a clone (the prefab is assigned to a public property of a script, which I assign using the editor, which is the e.Weapon):

```
Instantiate(e.Weapon, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity, rightHand.transform);
```

I am parenting it to my character's right hand. But whenever the clone gets created, it has different position than the one I have in my code. It appears like this:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: is your object child of another one?

Comment: @virtouso: yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First guess: It sounds like you have a parent gameObject and you instantiate it in world space [0, 0, 0]. Then your position would of course be something else than [0, 0, 0] because the inspector would show the local position to its parent, not world position. The Instantiate method has overloads with a Boolean for spawning objects in world position. However I'd assume the Instantiate method would use local space for the vector anyway, given that it allows you to assign a parent. Have a look into that.

Another guess: You set the position somewhere else by code upon Awake() or Start() of a script on the instantiated item. In this case look into all scripts attached to it.

Comment: Using the one with the boolean overload worked when I gave it a false value. I didn't use it at first because I thought it was false by default.